# When does EMR bootstrap actions run

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark

I am creating an AWS cluster and I have a bootstrap action to change spark-defaults.conf.

Server is keep getting terminated saying

> can't read /etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf: No such file or
>   directory

Though if I skip this and check on server the files does exist. So I assume the order of things are not correct. I am using Spark 1.6.1 by provided EMR 4.5 so it should be installed by default.

Any clues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not change Spark configurations in a bootstrap action. Instead you should specify any changes you have to `spark-defaults` in a special `json` file you need to add when launching the cluster. If you use the `cli` to launch, the command should look something like this:

```
 aws --profile MY_PROFILE emr create-cluster \
 --release-label emr-4.6.0 \
 --applications Name=Spark Name=Ganglia Name=Zeppelin-Sandbox \
 --name "Name of my cluster" \
 --configurations file:///path/to/my/emr-configuration.json \
 ...
 --bootstrap-actions ....
 --step ...
```

In the `emr-configuration.json` file you then set your changes to `spark-defaults`. An example could be:

```
[
  {
    "Classification": "capacity-scheduler",
    "Properties": {
      "yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator": "org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator"
    }
  },
  {
    "Classification": "spark",
    "Properties": {
      "maximizeResourceAllocation": "true"
    }
  },
  {
    "Classification": "spark-defaults",
    "Properties": {
      "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled": "true",
      "spark.executor.cores":"7"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Unfortunately the EMR JSON config does not honor all of the spark configuration options. If you need to change things like spark.driver.extraClassPath or spark.executor.extraClassPath, the JSON does not allow you to do so. How would you change those options without using bootstrap actions?

Comment: @Drahkar I was unaware that the spark.xx.extraClassPath cannot be set through the config file, but I assume that you can still specify them as options to your step, like `--steps Name=MyJob,Type=Spark,Args=[--master,yarn-client,--conf,spark.driver.extraClassPath=/extra/class/path/...]`??

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this goal is to use the Steps definition at a CloudFormation template for example... as Steps will run particularly at your Master node which holds the spark-default.conf file.